# Lists in functional programming, more specifically in Haskell

Tags: list, function, haskell, functional-programming

I am studying Haskell and saw this question :

```
h [] = []
h [x] = []
h (x:y:ys) = (x <= y): (h (y:ys))
```

the questions are, (1) what is the output type of `h`? (2) if length of `xs` is 100 then what is length of `h xs`? (3) calculate `h [1..5]` and (4) `h [1,2,1,2,1]`

I don't understand how to proceed with this.  What does the third condition `h (x:y:ys) = (x <= y): (h (y:ys))` mean ?

Comment: You could rewrite the function as `h s = zipWith (<=) s (tail s)` which might make it easier to read.

Comment: @Taren: not entirely because the original `h` will return `[]` for the empty list whereas you definition will crash. But I admit it is a detail :).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Actually, if s is empty (tail s) is never evaluated and it works fine! All hail to laziness or something.

Comment: @Taren: Well here you run in *undefined* behavior :). It has nothing to do with laziness itself, but with the fact that the first operand is evaluated first. One could write a `zip` function that first verifies the second operand :) for instance `zipWith f _ [] = []`, `zipWith f [] _ = []`, `zipWith f (x:xs) (y:ys) = (f x y) : zipWith f xs ys` could fail :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Can't think of any function in the prelude that is lazy in its first argument but you are totally right.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Not really undefined: the [Haskell report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html) gives a specification of zipWith. Your definition wouldn't be compatible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what does the third condition `h (x:y:ys) = (x <= y): (h (y:ys))` really mean ?

Well it is short for:

```
h (x:(y:ys)) = (x <= y): (h (y:ys))
```

Well it matches given the list contains **at least two elements**. In that case it compares the first with the second element `x <= y` and if the outcome, a `Bool` is placed in the head of the resulting list. It next does a recursive call to `h` with the second element and the remaining elements.

So what does the function calculates? **(1)** For a given list of *n* elements, it returns a list of *n-1* booleans that says for every two consecutive numbers whether the list is (not strictly) increasing. So to answer you first question.

Furthermore for a given list of *n* elements, it returns a list of *n-1* elements, so if you give it a list of 100 elements, it **(2)** returns a list of 99 elements.

Finally for `h [1..5]` it means we will get **(3)** `[True,True,True,True]` and for `h [1,2,1,2,1]` we will get **(4)** `[True,False,True,False]`.

Answer (score 4):

The full type of `h` is `Ord a => [a] -> [Bool]`.

1. The first two equations imply that both the input and output are lists of some type. For our first pass, we'll assume `h :: [a] -> [b]`; we'll figure out what constraints, if any, belong on `a` and `b` next.
2. The first two values in the input list in the 3rd equation are used by `(<=) :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool`, so we now know that the input list must be `Ord a => [a]`.
3. Further, the result of `(<=)` is prepended to the return value of the recursive call to `h`. For that to work, since `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`, we know that `h` must return a value of type `[Bool]`.